# Collection with index and hash access

Tags: java, collections, contains, hashcode

I need a collection class which has both: quick index and hash access.
Now I have ArrayList. It has good index acces, but his `contains` method is not performant. HashSet has good `contains` implementation but no indexed acces. Which collection has both? Probably something from Apache?
Or should I create my own collection class which has both: ArrayList for indexed acces and HashSet for `contains` check?

Just for clarification: i need both `get(int index)` and `contains(Object o)`

Comment: You own data structure which contains both (or some variation on that) is probably the way to go.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want this?

Comment: Yes I can. I have legacy code, which use nearly all methods of a List object (ArrayList). I have no chance to rewrite it, but I want to increase its performance. The main problem here are contains and indexOf methods because they have linear performance.

Answer (score 1):

If indexed access performance is not a problem the closest match is LinkedHashSet whose API says that it is

*Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order.*

at least I dont think that the performance will be be worse than that of LinkedListPerformance. Otherwise I cannot see no alternative but your ArrayList + HashTable solution

Comment: I'm not sure that it's really better

Answer (score 0):

If you are traversing the index from start to finish, I think this might satisfy your needs: [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

If you need to randomly access via the index, as well as hash access, if no-one else has a better suggestion I guess you can make your own collection which does both.

Comment: As far as I can see, indexed access would be `O(n)`, which is not particularly efficient.

Comment: LinkedHashSet has no method 'get(int index)'

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Yes, but you can use the iterator to simulate it.

Comment: Sure but in this case I will have the same performance bottleneck on another place.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this; use combination of **Hash** technique as well as **list** to get best of both worlds :)

```
class DataStructure<Integer>{
   Hash<Integer,Integer> hash = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void add(Integer i){
        hash.add(i,i);
        list.add(i);
    }
    public Integer get(int index){
        return list.get(index);
    }
   ...
} //used Integers to make it simpler
```

So object; you keep in **HashMap/HashSet** as well as **ArrayList**.

So if you want to use

```
 contains method : call hashed contains method.

 get an object with index: use array to return the value
```

Just make sure that you have both these collections in sync. And take care of updation/deletion in both data structures.

Comment: It's the last loophole, which I would use, if I cannot find something better

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact lookup times, but maybe you could use some implementation of the [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You could store you objects with `map.put(objectHash, obj)`.

Then you could verify that you have a certain object with:

```
boolean contained = map.containsValue(obj);
```

And you can use the hash to lookup an object in the map:

```
MyObject object = map.get(objectHash);
```

Though, the only downfall is that you would need to know your hashes on this lookup call which may not be probably in your implementation.

Comment: containsValue for HashMap has the same performance as contains of a list - the linear. I wish the logarithmical (if possible of course).

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Ahh, I was not aware of that. Do you have a reference of where you found that out?

Comment: Simply see the implementation of HashMap. Method containsValue iterates over all entries and checks for equality like the contains method of ArrayList.